# Best practice for using pipenv Pipfile and Pipfile.lock across multiple platforms

Tags: python, pipenv

Is there a best practice for using `pipenv` for deterministic builds when you're going to be developing and running application code on multiple platforms (i.e. Windows, Linux, and Mac)?

For instance, [the requirements for `pytest` defines the `atomicwrites` library as a conditional dependency](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/setup.cfg#L50) if you are installing `pytest` in a Windows-based Python environment.

However, if I define...

```sh
[dev-packages]
pytest = "*"
```

as a requirement in my project's `Pipfile` and run `pipenv install --dev` to generate my initial `Pipfile.lock` in a Linux-based Python environment, then `atomicwrites` is neither installed nor specified in any way in the resulting `Pipfile.lock` file.

Later, after I `git commit` my new Linux-generated `Pipfile.lock`, either I or someone else will eventually pull that committed `Pipfile.lock` file down onto their Windows machine and will run `pipenv install --dev` to generate their own local `pipenv` environment.

- However, when they go to run the `pytest` test-runner, it will fail because `atomicwrites` will not have been installed in their `pipenv` environment, therefore the `pytest` command will fail because of the missing dependency.
- What's more, my Windows test-build will also fail when using a CI service like GitHub Actions or Azure Pipelines because `pipenv` will fail to install the `atomicwrites` dependency there too (because it will not be specified in the repo's `Pipfile.lock` specifications).

This `pytest` example is a super simple example of this issue. In this case, it'd be easy enough just to add `atomicwrites` as one of my `[dev-packages]` requirements in my `Pipfile` so that it gets installed regardless of the platform, or to even add `sys_platform = "== 'win32'"` to specify that it should only be installed by `pipenv` on Windows platforms.

However, these platform-conditional dependencies become a much harder issue to deal with when my project has many dependencies, all with their own platform-conditional dependencies.

I've seen this issue discussed in a couple different locations, [such as here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/210), [and here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3702).

However, I have yet to find any straightforward method for dealing with this (short of not using `pipenv` or deleting the `Pipfile.lock` file prior to running `pipenv install --dev` on a different platform).

Do any `pipenv` users out there have a recommended best practice for dealing with this multiple-os `Pipfile.lock` install issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously too late to be helpful to you, but I have found that generating the lock file in these multiple environments while keeping outdated versions resolves most of the problems with pipenv.

For example, our CI/CD uses GitHub images, so in a Windows Subsystem for Linux shell:

```
pipenv install --dev
```

Then, in a Windows shell

```
pipenv install --dev --keep-outdated
```

However, running in Windows can sometimes pin a dependency to that platform (colorama currently does this as of this answer's writing). To avoid that, you can regenerate the lock file again in WSL:

```
pipenv lock --dev --keep-outdated
```

This will keep the "outdated" packages from a Windows-only environment, but will generally fix the platform conditionals.

Note that the dance above is ultimately not foolproof--I found this question because this exact method was not working for `atomicwrites`. However, it seems to resolve the vast majority of issues and those that cannot generally can be solved by adding the package to your dependencies manually.